# Show using the formal definition of a limit that the following sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

The sequence that I'm asked to prove is convergent is this...

$\frac{2}{n^{2}+n+1}$

I know this converges to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

So far I have this:

$|\frac{2}{n^2+n+1}|<\epsilon$

$\frac{2}{\epsilon}<n^2+n+1$

$\frac{2}{\epsilon}-1<n^2+n$

I don't know how to get $n$ on its own on one side of the inequality, or if that is what I should be going for in general. So far in our lectures we've always proved a sequence converges to a value $\forall n\geq n_{0}$ if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n^2+n+1>n$, $0<\frac2{n^2+n+1}<\frac2n$. So, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac2N<\varepsilon(\iff N>\frac2\varepsilon)$, and then$$n\geqslant N\implies\frac2n\leqslant\frac2N<\varepsilon\implies0<\frac2{n^2+n+1}<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\frac{2}{n^2 +n + 1}< \frac{2}{n^2}<\epsilon.$$